# Newcommand leads to no error nor output

Tags: beamer, debugging

I'm writing a wrapper for some output. I have to files, `beamer.tex` which has content as

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{beamer}

% add page numbers for malmoe
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}
\usetheme{Malmoe}
\date{}
\input{content}
```

and the `content.tex`, which has something along the lines of

```
\newcommand{\pdfslide}[1]{
\begin{frame}[plain]
\vspace*{-1pt}
\makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics[page=1,width=\paperwidth]{#1}}
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\mode*
\pdfslide{fig4.pdf}

\end{document}
```

If I, instead of writing the `pdfslide` command, directly put the command into the document (with fig4.pdf replacing #1), I get the correct output. The way it stands here, I don't (the remainder of the document gets processed correctly, just the pdf slide is missing). I also don't get any error message (which I suppose comes from my `\include` structure).

Does anyone spot the error? Or how can I debug this in this situation?

Comment: Why `\include` and not `\input`?

Comment: Keep confusing the two, fixed that. Doesn't give me error message or change nothing, though.

Comment: I am no beamer expert, but what does `\mode*` do? If I comment it out, the code works, but I find the `\input{content}` with the whole `\begin{document}...\end{document}` stuff a little bit weird

Comment: @FooBar: I got it: `\mode*` ignores everything outside of a `frame` environment. Your `\pgfslide` command is a wrapper for a `frame` environment, but it's outside ;-) That's why the 'naked' code without `\newcommand` works

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'error' is `\mode*` as it forces `beamer` to ignore everything outside of `frame` environments, which is the case for the `\pgfslide` command, as it is used inside a `frame` environment.

Commenting/deleting `\mode*` will lead to a successful compilation with a frame containing the included graphics.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% add page numbers for malmoe
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}
\usetheme{Malmoe}
\date{}
\input{content}
```

### content.tex

```
\newcommand{\pdfslide}[1]{
\begin{frame}[plain]
\vspace*{-1pt}
\makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics[page=1,width=\paperwidth]{#1}}
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
%\mode*  Must be switched off!!
\pdfslide{fig4.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And there is no way to reconcile the two? I'd still like to use mode* to add notes for the handouts as I am used to.

Comment: @FooBar: You should use `\mode<mode option>` for such cases. See the `beamer` documentation for such mode options